# How to add Map values into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arrays, maps

> I want to add map values into an arraylist.This is my current code.

```
  ArrayList<Map<String, String>> itemData = new ArrayList<>();
    int index =0;

    Map<String, String> itemselected = new HashMap<>();
    itemselected.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("cstName", textViewCstName.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("contact", textViewCstph.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("bill_type", billType);//null

    itemData.add(index,itemselected);
    index++;
```

> This is the output that i get.
>
> [{rate=24000,weight=21.000,desc=item description,makingAmt=200,cstName=Test customer,sum_total=52094.46,vat=1021.46,itemTotal=51073,barcode=BQSP78BB,net_rate=24200,invoiceNo=1842,bill_type=estimate,contact=+91-8600931386}]
>
> This is the output I am expecting.
>
> [{rate=24000,weight=21.000,desc=item description,makingAmt=200,cstName=Test customer,sum_total=52094.46,vat=1021.46,itemTotal=51073,barcode=BQSP78BB,net_rate=24200,invoiceNo=1842,bill_type=estimate,contact=+91-8600931386},{rate=24000,weight=21.000,desc=item description,makingAmt=200,cstName=Test customer,sum_total=52094.46,vat=1021.46,itemTotal=51073,barcode=BQSP79BB,net_rate=24200,invoiceNo=1842,bill_type=estimate,contact=+91-8600931386}, 
>   {rate=24000,weight=21.000,desc=item description,makingAmt=200,cstName=Test customer,sum_total=52094.46,vat=1021.46,itemTotal=51073,barcode=BQSP80BB,net_rate=24200,invoiceNo=1842,bill_type=estimate,contact=+91-8600931386}]
>
> I have a method called showItem() that contains itemTable().This is code for itemTable()

```
    private void itemTable(String itembarcode, String itemdesc, String weight, String rate, String making, String netrate, String total) {
    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    rowParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 0);

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(AddInvEst.this);
    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableParams);


    TableRow newRow = new TableRow(AddInvEst.this);
    newRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

    barCode = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    barCode.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    barCode.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    itemDesc = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    itemDesc.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    itemDesc.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    weightLine = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    weightLine.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.75f));
    weightLine.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    rateAmount = new EditText(AddInvEst.this);
    rateAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    rateAmount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    rateAmount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    //rateAmount.setSelection(rateAmount.getText().length());
    rateAmount.addTextChangedListener(rateTextWatcher);

    makingAmount = new EditText(AddInvEst.this);

    makingAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    makingAmount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    makingAmount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    makingAmount.addTextChangedListener(mkAmountTextWatcher);

    netRate = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    netRate.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    netRate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    netrates.add(netrate);

    itemtotal = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    itemtotal.setTag(count);
    itemtotal.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    itemtotal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    Toast.makeText(AddInvEst.this, "item count is " + itemtotal.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    totals.add(total);
    itemtotal.addTextChangedListener(totalTextWatcher);

    double[] doubleList = new double[totals.size()];
    double sum = 0.0d;
    for (int i = 0; i < totals.size(); ++i) {
        doubleList[i] = Double.parseDouble(totals.get(i));
        sum += doubleList[i];
    }

    barCode.setText(itembarcode);
    itemDesc.setText(itemdesc);
    weightLine.setText(weight);
    rateAmount.setText(rate);
    makingAmount.setText(making);
    netRate.setText(netrate);
    itemtotal.setText(total);
    textViewSum.setText(sum * (0.02) + sum + "");//set total text to sum
    textViewVat.setText(sum * (0.02) + "");

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> itemData = new ArrayList<>();
    int index =0;

    Map<String, String> itemselected = new HashMap<>();
    itemselected.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("cstName", textViewCstName.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("contact", textViewCstph.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());//d
    itemselected.put("bill_type", billType);//null

    itemData.add(index,itemselected);
    index++;




    /*JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        Toast.makeText(AddInvEst.this, "here the count is : "+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            jsonArray.put(count-1 ,itemselected);
        jsonObject.put("itemSelected", jsonArray);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    newRow.addView(barCode);
    newRow.addView(itemDesc);
    newRow.addView(weightLine);
    newRow.addView(rateAmount);
    newRow.addView(makingAmount);
    newRow.addView(netRate);
    newRow.addView(itemtotal);
    itemTable.addView(newRow);

    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_display);
    display.setText(itemData.toString());

    Toast.makeText(AddInvEst.this, itemData.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

> This code for showItem()

```
    private void showItem(String json) {
    String itembarcode = "";
    String itemdesc = "";
    String weight = "";
    String rate = "";
    String making = "";
    String netrate = "";
    String total = "";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ParseBarcode.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject itemData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        itembarcode = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_BARCODE);
        itemdesc = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_DESC);
        weight = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_WEIGHT);
        rate = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_RATE);
        making = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_MAKING);
        netrate = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_NETRATE);
        total = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_TOTAL);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //dynamic table generation code

    itemTable(itembarcode, itemdesc, weight, rate, making, netrate, total);
}
```

> This is where I call showItem in the else block.

```
   private void sendBarcode(final String url, final String barcodeNo) {
    final Context context = getApplicationContext();
    //String url = ITEM_URL+barcodeNum+toString().trim();
    if (barcodeNo.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(AddInvEst.this, "Please enter a valid barcode number ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(AddInvEst.this, "Please wait...", "Fetching...", false, false);

    StringRequest stringReq = new StringRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("notfound")) {
                        final Dialog dialogCrash = new Dialog(AddInvEst.this);
                        dialogCrash.setContentView(R.layout.crashreport);
                        TextView crashreport = (TextView) dialogCrash.findViewById(R.id.tv_crashcode);
                        crashreport.setText("Please Enter a valid Barcode Number ...");

                        Button bt_crash = (Button) dialogCrash.findViewById(R.id.bt_crash);
                        bt_crash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialogCrash.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        dialogCrash.show();
                        loading.dismiss();

                    } else {

                        loading.dismiss();
                        showItem(response);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Your Internet connection is slow or not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue reqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    reqQueue.add(stringReq);
}
```

> And sendBarcode is what I call onClick of a button.

Comment: How you retrieved data from itemData?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty I am simply using a Toast to display the data.  Toast.makeText(AddInvEst.this, itemData.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @AnshulTyagi can you give a code example.I am new to programming.

Comment: It looks like you want your output to contain multiple hash maps, but there's no loop in your code.

Comment: @ajb I tried using a for loop but it would print the same values again and again.Can you give an example as to how i can use it in a correct way.Thanks

Comment: If you really don't know how to write a loop, look over this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html.  If you generally know how to write loops but couldn't get this one to work, please post your code so that we can help point out what you did wrong.

Comment: your arraylist is always new allocation.
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> itemData = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @LEETAEJUN how can I change or modify it to get the required output.Please bare with me as i am new to programming.

Comment: if you want to have multiple hashmaps, 'itemData' move to class variable. and new allocation in constructor. and hashmaps add to 'itemData'  data in 'itemTable' method

Comment: @LEETAEJUN Thank you so much this solved my problem

Comment: good. have a nice today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A {
    List<Map<String,String>> itemData;

    public A() {
        itemData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void itemTable {
         ...
        int index =0;

        Map<String, String> itemselected = new HashMap<>();
        itemselected.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("cstName", textViewCstName.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("contact", textViewCstph.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("bill_type", billType);//null

        itemData.add(index,itemselected);
        index++;

         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well If you think result oriented, for what you want, You can make this whole process quite easy by having your own Item class. Which will reduce your coding on UI thread.

Make a class **Item.java**

package day.eight;

```
public class Item {

    private int rate = 0;
    private int weight = 0;
    private String desc = null;
    private int makingAmt = 0;
    private String cstName = null;
    private float sum_total = 0;
    private float vat = 0;
    private int itemTotal = 0;
    private String barcode = null;
    private int net_rate = 0;
    private int invoiceNo = 0;
    private String bill_type = null;
    private String contact = null;

    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }
    public void setRate(int rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public int getMakingAmt() {
        return makingAmt;
    }
    public void setMakingAmt(int makingAmt) {
        this.makingAmt = makingAmt;
    }
    public String getCstName() {
        return cstName;
    }
    public void setCstName(String cstName) {
        this.cstName = cstName;
    }
    public float getSum_total() {
        return sum_total;
    }
    public void setSum_total(float sum_total) {
        this.sum_total = sum_total;
    }
    public float getVat() {
        return vat;
    }
    public void setVat(float vat) {
        this.vat = vat;
    }
    public int getItemTotal() {
        return itemTotal;
    }
    public void setItemTotal(int itemTotal) {
        this.itemTotal = itemTotal;
    }
    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }
    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }
    public int getNet_rate() {
        return net_rate;
    }
    public void setNet_rate(int net_rate) {
        this.net_rate = net_rate;
    }
    public int getInvoiceNo() {
        return invoiceNo;
    }
    public void setInvoiceNo(int invoiceNo) {
        this.invoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    }
    public String getBill_type() {
        return bill_type;
    }
    public void setBill_type(String bill_type) {
        this.bill_type = bill_type;
    }
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

Now that you have all the properties required for your Item `object` its time to put it to test,

I mean, we will just check if we can create it's Objects and make desired `JSON` string and try to get back out `Object` from `JSON` we would create.

Following code is just test code to make desired `JSON` data, it's up to you how you want to create your data in production

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class ItemTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setRate(248 + i);
            item.setWeight(21 + i);
            item.setDesc("itemdescription: " + i);
            item.setMakingAmt(200 + i);
            item.setCstName("Testcustomer: " + i);
            item.setSum_total((float) (52094.46 + i));
            item.setVat((float) 1021.46 + i);
            item.setItemTotal(200);
            item.setBarcode("BQSP78BB" + i);
            item.setNet_rate(2450 + i);
            item.setInvoiceNo(1845 + i);
            item.setBill_type("estimate: +i");
            item.setContact("+91-8600931386");
            items.add(item);
        }

        /**
         * This code will convert your ArrayList object to a equivalent JSON
         * String
         */
        String result = (new Gson()).toJson(items);
        System.out.println("" + result);

        /**
         * This code will convert your JSON String to a equivalent ArrayList
         * Object
         */
        ArrayList<Item> items2 = (new Gson()).fromJson(result,new TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>() {}.getType());
    }
}
```

> Output

```
[
  {
    "rate": 248,
    "weight": 21,
    "desc": "itemdescription: 0",
    "makingAmt": 200,
    "cstName": "Testcustomer: 0",
    "sum_total": 52094.46,
    "vat": 1021.46,
    "itemTotal": 200,
    "barcode": "BQSP78BB0",
    "net_rate": 2450,
    "invoiceNo": 1845,
    "bill_type": "estimate: +i",
    "contact": "+91-8600931386"
  },
  {
    "rate": 249,
    "weight": 22,
    "desc": "itemdescription: 1",
    "makingAmt": 201,
    "cstName": "Testcustomer: 1",
    "sum_total": 52095.46,
    "vat": 1022.46,
    "itemTotal": 200,
    "barcode": "BQSP78BB1",
    "net_rate": 2451,
    "invoiceNo": 1846,
    "bill_type": "estimate: +i",
    "contact": "+91-8600931386"
  },
  {
    "rate": 250,
    "weight": 23,
    "desc": "itemdescription: 2",
    "makingAmt": 202,
    "cstName": "Testcustomer: 2",
    "sum_total": 52096.46,
    "vat": 1023.46,
    "itemTotal": 200,
    "barcode": "BQSP78BB2",
    "net_rate": 2452,
    "invoiceNo": 1847,
    "bill_type": "estimate: +i",
    "contact": "+91-8600931386"
  }
]
```